# passing List<Account> to webervice method

Tags: apex, rest-api

I am using 2 different salesforce instances & I want to insert multiple accounts from one salesforce organs to another using rest API call.

**code for destination:**

```
@HTTPPost  
  webservice static List<Account> InsertMultipleAccounts()  
  {
    List<Account> newaccList=new List<Account>();    

    RestRequest req=RestContext.Request;

    RestResponse res=RestContext.Response;

    string req_body=req.RequestBody.ToString();

    if (req_body != NULL)
    {
      NewAccList=(List<Account>)Json.deserialize(req_body,List<Account>.class);
  if (NewAccList != NULL)
      {
         Database.Insert(NewAccList);
      }
    }
 return newaccList;  
}
```

**code for source:**

```
public class IntegrateAccountRestController
{ 
 public string jsonList{get;set;}
public IntegrateAccountRestController()
    {
      a = new Account();  //only for HTTPPOST
    }
public PageReference InsertMultipleAccounts()  //Is a button in vf page
    {
       if (Helper.GetAccessToken() != NULL)  //for generating access token
       {
          Http h = new Http();
          HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
          req.setMethod('POST');
           req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+Helper.GetAccessToken().access_token);

          req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json; charset=UTF-8'); 
          req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
          req.setEndpoint('https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/AccountRest');   

          String dataupload = JSON.serialize(a);

          req.setBody(dataupload);

          HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

          jsonList=res.getBody();
     }
   return NULL;
    }
}
```

In source I have created a Vf page to enter the account name as    and I have button InsertMultipleAccounts 
How to have multiple records in json?

Comment: why are you using webservice for destination instead of Apex Rest service?